# Matching lines in file, with 2 lists of strings in order

Tags: text-processing, grep, python

I am trying to match access-list lines in a file where certain environments (list A) are destination, and other environments (list B) are the source. And vice versa.

This is on an Ubuntu server.

Problem is that these lists are both around ~15 lines, which makes for quite a bit of combinations, and a very long grep command. And the file being searched in is around ~3000 lines total.

I know I can match lines in a file with lines in a file via `grep -f`, but I haven't been able to find a solution to my specific search requirements, where I am searching from 2 lists, and the order matters.

Example of what I would want to do (the parentheses are intentional, since I am searching in a file that has relevant environment appended to IP addresses per line):

List A contents:

```
(One)
Two
Three
```

List B contents:

```
(Four)
(Five)
(Six)
```

File that is being searched in:

```
access-list acl-name line 1 extended permit tcp host 1.2.3.4 (One) host 5.6.7.8 Two eq ssh
access-list acl-name line 1 extended permit tcp host 1.2.3.4 (One) host 5.6.7.8 (Four) eq ssh
access-list acl-name line 1 extended permit tcp host 1.2.3.4 (Four) host 5.6.7.8 Three eq ssh
access-list acl-name line 1 extended permit tcp host 1.2.3.4 (Six) host 5.6.7.8 (One) eq ssh
access-list acl-name line 1 extended permit tcp host 1.2.3.4 (Five) host 5.6.7.8 (Five) eq ssh
```

Desired output (List A as destination):

```
access-list acl-name line 1 extended permit tcp host 1.2.3.4 (Six) host 5.6.7.8 (One) eq ssh
access-list acl-name line 1 extended permit tcp host 1.2.3.4 (Four) host 5.6.7.8 Three eq ssh
```

Desired output (List B as destination):

```
access-list acl-name line 1 extended permit tcp host 1.2.3.4 (One) host 5.6.7.8 (Four) eq ssh
```

I am open to any commands usable on Ubuntu or even a python script.

Right now, my grep search look something like this (for matching lines where List B is destination, and List A is source)

```
grep -iE '\(One\).*\(Four\)|Two.*\(Four\)|Three.*\(Four\)|\(One\).*\(Five\) and so on... '
```

Any help is appreciated, so I hopefully can reduce my current script from the 15000 characters :)

Comment: Are all source and destination strings in List A and List B contiguous strings, or can they contain whitespace?

Comment: @terdon Yes that is intentional, since it roughly represents the actual list, where only few lines in List A has parentheses. And every line in List B has parentheses.

Comment: @AdminBee a few lines have a whitespace

Comment: @Thor No, they are Cisco ASA access-lists, and have had environments appended after each IP in the access-list, so they are preceeded by either an IPv4 address or an IPv4 subnet mask

Comment: @all im going to edit the post, since the example access-lists were misleading and inaccurate

Comment: Please make sure to include examples with whitespace, the presence of whitespace changes everything. Will you _always_ have parentheses when there is whietespace? If not, how can we identify the match? Can the src or dst strings appear more than once on the line?

Comment: Subnet mask in what format? CIDR?

Comment: You changed the input/output and now it's even less clear than before what you're trying to do.  You talk about `certain environments (list A) are destination, and other environments (list B) are the source` but then you later say `List A as destination` and `List B as destination` so are you trying to match lines where values from LiatsA and ListB are both present or just one of them? If just one is it supposed to match in  the earlier (source?) or later (destination?) location? If the intent is to find lines where FileB values match why isn't the input line with `(Five)` in the output?

Comment: @Thor Subnet mask in format: 255.255.255.0 for example. And a network address in front of that of course. 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 (One)

Comment: @Ed Morton One entry from each list needs to be present in matched lines, not just one. And i need 2 outputs, one where A is src and B is dst (source being present first and destination last) and another where it is the opposite.

I can see that i have been a bit too broad in my statements, i apologize, but i appreciate the feedback and getting closer to a possible solution

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clearly state your requirements and explain the expected output, including stating if 1 run of the desired tool should produce both output files or if it's 2 different runs of the tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have GNU Awk available (for the `FPAT` internal variable), the following program should work:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="host ([[:digit:]]+.){3}[[:digit:]]+ [^ ]+"}
     t=="src"{src[$0];next}
     t=="dst"{dest[$0];next}
     {split($1,a,/ /);lsrc=a[3]; split($2,a,/ /);ldst=a[3]}
     (lsrc in src && ldst in dest)' t="src" listA t="dst" listB t="" access
```

The program will be called with three files to process, where for each of the processing runs an `awk` variable `t` is set to a different value to allow identifying which file is processed.

- If `t` is set to `src`, the program assumes this is the "source" list and read the line content into an associative array `src` (but populate only the array indices, not actually assign any value to that entry). Processing is then immediately skipped to the next line of the file. *Note that there must be no leading or trailing spaces since they would otherwise be included in the pattern match. Also, the matching later will assume that these lines contain only one contiguous string, without internal spaces.*
- If `t` is set to `dst`, the program assumes this is the "destination" list and will similarly register all line content in an array `dest`.

If `t` has any other value, the program assumes it is in the "main" access list and performs the actual matching.

- Here, the `FPAT` internal variable, set in the `BEGIN` section, comes into play. It will consider as a "field" all portions that match the pattern "`host`, followed by an IPv4 address (only basic formal check performed), followed by a single contiguous string, each separated by a single space".
- The first such field contains the "source" part. It will be split at the spaces into an array `a`, with the third array entry (the "environment" part) stored in the local variable `lsrc`.
- The second such field will be treated similarly, with the "environment" part stored in the local variable `ldst`.
- Outside of the rule blocks is the boolean condition that will determine whether the line is printed or not. The line is printed if the `lsrc` is contained in the indices of array `src` *and* the `ldst` is contained in the indices of array `dest`.

The result, using `listA` as first file and `listB` as second file would be:

```
> awk ' ... ' t="src" listA t="dst" listB t="" access
access-list acl-name line 1 extended permit tcp host 1.2.3.4 (One) host 5.6.7.8 (Four) eq ssh
```

In the reverse case, using `listB` as first file and `listA` as second file:

```
> awk ' ... ' t="src" listB t="dst" listA t="" access
access-list acl-name line 1 extended permit tcp host 1.2.3.4 (Four) host 5.6.7.8 Three eq ssh
access-list acl-name line 1 extended permit tcp host 1.2.3.4 (Six) host 5.6.7.8 (One) eq ssh
```